# Drawing from a Service in Android

Tags: android, service, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I'm trying to draw (IE GLSurfaceView) from a Service and so that it runs in the background.

I know this is possible because the app Transparant Screen gives a perfect example of this.

However, i have no idea how to accomplish this.

So far, i created a activity and a service and some Opengl draw methods. 
I also made the GlSurfaceview and activity transparant, but ofcourse touches won't be redirected to the layer under (child).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has been designed to be used that way,
however you can reach activity from service quiet easily (using a singleton) and then you should be able to draw into a canvas or drawable and then invalidate the view to draw your offline one ...

Note I am answering on a slightly different context, by using a 2D widget view.

I need to check my own to make sure it is the best of the worse cases... I'll may update this post later